# JUnit Parameterized data injection

Tags: java, spring, junit, parameterized

I'm creating a test which takes it's data from an external source, in my case a json file. I'm using JUnit Parameterized for data injection in the corresponding fields.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyTest extends CommonTest
{   
    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public String field1;
    @Parameterized.Parameter(1)
    public String field2;

    public static Collection<Object[]> params() throws PropertyNotFoundException 
    {    
        final JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader("path to the json file"));
        // here I am reading the tests sampledata from the json file
    }    
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/test-spring.xml"})
@ActiveProfiles(resolver = SpringActiveProfileResolver.class)
public class CommonTest
{
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();

    ...
}
```

For the moment I use a static path to the external source in the params() method. How can I use a relative path to this external source and not have it hardcoded? The json file is next to the test-spring.xml

My issue here is that the params() method is static and can't inject something through Spring to solve it.

How can I address this issue?

Comment: MyTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path relative to src/test/resources")

This returns an InputStream, but FileReader isA InputStreamReader, so you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that `test-spring.xml` is at the root of your classpath, so if the json file is also, then you can get file handle like this...

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/file.json");
File file = resource.getFile();
```

You may also want to take a look at [ClassRelativeResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassRelativeResourceLoader.html) if you want to keep the json file next to your test class